# Split an integer into an array of digits

Tags: java

I need to take an inputted integer, break the digits apart, and then finally do calculations with them. I think the best way of doing this is by using an array. How do I take the int and put  its digits into the array?

Comment: [Exactly what you will need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389264/how-to-get-the-separate-digits-of-an-int-number). Notice that the array can then be operated on. 

  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/converting.html

Comment: @JavaWithJava You should probably not have deleted the entire question.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't want people to waste time trying to solve a problem with a solution. I wasn't thinking about how other people with the same problem can look here.

Comment: In that case - you could accept an answer indicating that the problem has been solved.

Comment: There will be no point of forum, if the questions being resolved are deleted.. Also, there is no point of answers without a question.. (Other users might think like this in future) if they see this post.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int value = 234567;
String[] digits = Integer.toString(value).split("");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits));
```

Result:

```
[, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Take into account that the first (0) position is empty.

Another way using integers:

```
int value = 234567;
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        while(value > 0){
            result.add(value%10);
            value = value/10;
        }
        Collections.reverse(result);
        System.out.println(result);
```

Result:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: I think the OP wants an `int[]` as opposed to a `String[]`.

Comment: For nicer result try maybe `split("(?<=\\d)");` or even better simple `toCharArray()`

Comment: Posted another solution (just for fun, A.R.S. solution is nice for me)

Comment: +1 for offering the mathematical way to do it, instead of simply abusing int to String conversion.

Comment: "abusing" seems a tad harsh wouldn't you say

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
int a = 1234321;

char[] c = ("" + a).toCharArray();
int[] digits = new int[c.length];
for (int i = 0 ; i < digits.length ; i++)
    digits[i] = c[i] - '0';

for (int i : digits) System.out.println(i);
```

Output:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   3
>   2
>   1

Comment: Why convert an int to a String and then to a char array, inefficiently, and 8 times, when you could do it 0 time using simple modulo arithmetics?

Comment: just use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));` instead of loop

Comment: I edited the code so as to not convert the int to a string repetitively. Now it's merely one string conversion and a series of subsequent subtractions.

Answer (score -3):

create the ArrayList integer type

```
 ArrayList<Integer> arl = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

then insert the values...

```
arl.add(56);
arl.add(74);
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but your answer doesn't compile, and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: He's not asking for that.. He is asking to break an integer number into single digits.. 56 into 5 and 6.. And you don't create an ArrayList over primitive types

Comment: You can't use generics with primitive data types. You need to use a wrapper class.