# Java Regex Metacharacters

Tags: java, regex, string

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389264/how-to-get-the-separate-digits-of-an-int-number) thread and one of users on it posted the following line of code:

```
String[] digits2 = number.split("(?<=.)");
```

I have consulted a couple of sources- like [1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) and [2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html)-to decipher what this code mean but I can't figure it out. Can anybody explain what the argument in the split() method means?

**Edit**: To anyone who has the same question as I had, here's another helpful [link](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). The overall expression means "after any character, but without capturing anything". Essentially, if the string looks like

```
ABC
```

then the matches would occur at `|`, between the characters.

```
A|B|C|
```

Comment: I know that "." matches any character except for line breaks, but what does "<=" mean in this context?

Comment: @Haque1 That's a sequence of metacharacters that tells the expression that the "." should not *capture* anything. The engine needs to see that a character is there, but it should not remove that character from the stream.

Comment: @Haque1 This is an unusual use of lookbehind. A more common way is like this: `(?<=tag:)"[^"]*"`. This expression matches a quoted string only when it is preceded by a `tag:` string.

Answer (score 1):

`.split("")` (on an empty string/pattern) will match the empty string at the start of the regex.  This is an additional empty string character that is undesirable.  `(?<=.)` is a zero-width assertion (does not consume any characters) that matches the zero-width space followed by any character (followed by because it is a lookbehind).  This splits on the empty string between each character, but not the empty space between the first character and the start of the string.

Comment: Zero-width space is the wrong term to use here; that's [a different thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space).

Comment: @Cairnarvon thanks for pointing this out ... which term would you prefer?

Comment: I want to say "character boundary", but that's not strictly right either. I'm not sure, to be honest.