# Java obtain digits from int like substring for a string?

Tags: java, int

I want to know how to extract digits from a number.

The only method I can think of is converting the number to a string, then use substring() - THEN convert back to int.

Would there be a more efficient way, such that it obtains a specific number like the substring() method, but for an int or a BigInteger?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389264/how-to-get-the-separate-digits-of-an-int-number

Comment: I would say that using the `substring` method would be the most *efficient*. However, you could do as these answers suggest and use the mod function or divide the number into its individual placeholder values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand how to do it, consider this:

- To remove all digits prior to digit `k` (counting from the back of the number), compute `x % pow(10, k+1)`
- To truncate the last `k` digits of a number compute `x / pow(10, k)`

Now you can construct a method that removes the initial part and drops the ending part as needed to compute a substring. Note that the same trick can be applied to numeric representations other than decimal by substituting `10` with the base of the number (i.e. `2` for binary numbers, `16` for hex numbers, and so on).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Perhaps I was unclear with my question, but this was the sort I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to extracting `1, 2, 3, 4` from `1234`, you can use the modulo operator `%` as follows:

```
int i = 1234;
while (i > 0) {
    System.out.println(i % 10);
    i = i / 10;
}
```

this would print `4, 3, 2, 1`. To get them in reverse order, you can use a stack to push the values and the pop them.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is something like this:

```
int current = number; 
do {
  System.out.println((current % 10));
  current = current / 10;
} while (currrent > 0);
```