# How do I use modulus in a while loop to get individual digits of an integer?

Tags: java, while-loop, modulo, modulus, integer-division

I'm hoping to find a way to use a while loop (not a for loop) to get the individual digits of an integer put in through command line. Right now, I have it hard coded for how to get individual digits if a four digit integer is entered, but if I enter a five digit number it obviously won't work. I'm thinking a while loop should be able to fix that but I'm not sure how...

Here is the code I have so far

Comment: You'll need an array or some kind of `List`.  You won't be able to do this with individual variables named `digit1`, `digit2`, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3389287/1114171

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (number > 0)
{
    digits.add(number%10);
    number /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
int number = 567;
int[] digits = new int[String.valueOf(number).length()];
while (number > 0)
{
    digits[String.valueOf(number).length()-1] = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits));
```

Might not be the most elegant solution, but it will give you the digits in the number, in the same order as they are in the number. Example `12345` will give the array a value of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` when it is output.