# how can i get single digit from four digit

Tags: java

I'm having trouble getting the individual digits of a number.
 you have simple integer variable containing 1234, How do you get the individual digits of the number
     for example: int s = 1234;

I need to store every digit in a separate variable like

```
String str1  = "1";
String str2 = "2";
String str3 = "3";
String str4 = "4";
```

Is it possible? how can I implement this? In above method I gave one static integer value.
could you please tell me both static and dynamic please guide me

Comment: Is this homeworks ? It looks like this... Please show us what you tried so far.

Comment: @mithrop i have an integer number, its come from server whether the value is 3 digit or four digit, i need to get every number and stored into separate variable this is the concept i am not getting any idea that is what i posted like this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the separate digits of an int number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389264/how-to-get-the-separate-digits-of-an-int-number)

Comment: @user3728511 : please [search in google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=split+digit+from+int+in+java) before asking any question.

Comment: Read the excellent Java documentation for String -- several functions there you can use.  And not sure what you mean by "static" vs "dynamic" -- a number is a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use % operator

```
 int num1,num2,num3,num4,temp;

num1=s%10;
temp=s/10;

num2=temp%10;
temp=temp/10;

num3=temp%10;
num4=temp/10;
```

then you can convert num1,2,3,4 to string

Answer (score 0):

Transform it to string and get the chat at the position you want.

```
    int index = 2;
    int value = 1234;
    int digitAt=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(value).charAt(index)));
```

so for example :

```
 String str1 =  String.valueOf(value).charAt(0);
 String str2 =  String.valueOf(value).charAt(1);
 String str3 =  String.valueOf(value).charAt(2);
 String str4 = String.valueOf(value).charAt(3);
```

Comment: could you tell me what is the purpose of index

Comment: index is the position that you want to get. If you want to get the digit on second position index should be 1 and so on

Comment: if i am using this line                         String str1 = (int) String.valueOf(value).charAt(0); the error is coming like Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String, if i change int instead of string error is not coming what can i do

Comment: Yes, you should remove the cast `(int)`

Comment: No, instead of (int) you have to call Integer.valueOf(...)

Comment: @Sebastian That will throw an error too. `String str1` is a string, not an Integer. And a `(int)` cast it's safe in this case.

Comment: @PedroOliveira The whole line should say `int digitAt= Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(value).charAt(index)));`

Only calling (int) will work but give you the int value of the char. That is not wanted.

Comment: @Sebastian You're right about `(int)` giving the value of the char. However `Integer.valueOf` will do the same thing. What we're looking for is `Integer.parseInt`

Comment: @PedroOliveira See the documentation of Integer.valueOd(String). It is just like Integer.parseInt

Comment: Have you tested what you're saying? Because I did and I'm sure parse it's different from valueof

Answer (score 0):

You can get the characters like this:

```
int s = 1234;
String t = String.valueOf(s);
String[] tArr = new String[t.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++){
    tArr[0] = String.valueOf(t.charAt(i));
}
```

So you will get the array of individual character as String.