# Check Single digit in int(Java)

Tags: java

How do you check a single digit in an int? I know for Strings you can use charAt(), but if you try to use it for an int it will return an error message. Is there any way to check a single digit and set it to a variable in a multiple digit number?

Comment: Convert int to String and use charAt, or use something like `(x/10...0)%10` (depending on digit you want to get).

Comment: @KickButtowski Regex works on `String` (text), not on `int`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389264/how-to-get-the-separate-digits-of-an-int-number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert `int` to String and can use `charAt` as follow

```
int a = 566;
String s = Integer.toString(a);
System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
```

Output:  5