# How to convert integer into place values?

Tags: java, integer

I have a problem here. I want to try to figure out how to take an integer, let's use 1234, and split into it's "place values." This means changing

```
1234
```

into

```
1000, 200, 30, 4
```

I am thinking about putting these into arrays, but im not sure what to do from there. My entire code will take any user input and turn it into roman numerals, and this is what i am thinking.

Comment: Think about `%`.

Comment: Roman numerals also use the non-decimal `V` and `L`. Make sure you don't forget those.

Comment: Take a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389264/how-to-get-the-separate-digits-of-an-int-number

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
import java.util.*;

public class First
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         int num = scan.nextInt();
         int i=1,mod;
         while(num>0)
         {
            mod = num % 10;
            System.out.println(mod*i);
            i=i*10;
            num = num/10;
         }
    }
}
```

This code will print the position value. You could store it in array other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

this gives you the expected output, you could add the number to an arry using variable `rem`, the integer `div` is `number of digits * 10`

```
    int num = 1234;
    int div = (int) Math.pow(10, (int)(Math.log10(num)));
    while(num > 0) {
        int rem = num / div;
        num = num % div;
        div /= 10;
        System.out.println("num : -> "+ rem);
    }
```