# command line arguments in java that print numbers in words

Tags: java

I want to a program in java that prints the number in word's. Can any body help me.
Exp like suppose user give 123 then program will prints "one two three only".

```
Class Test {
```

}

Comment: You need to provide example code showing your efforts and where you are having issues. This is not a homework request site.

Answer (score 0):

basically you need to convert String to integer
[How to convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java)
then get over the numbers one by one [How to get the separate digits of an int number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389264/how-to-get-the-separate-digits-of-an-int-number)
 and create a switch on each digit and the switch add String of number to String

```
String final ="";
switch(num){
case'1': final = final+"one";break;
.
.    
.
.
etc
```