# If a user inputs a 4 digit int, how do I use an array to extract each digit?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I'm creating a very basic encryption program, and I'm stuck. Essentially the user inputs a 4 digit int using a scanner and my goal is to, encrypt each digit, using a set formula. But i can't figure out how to, extract each digit and insert it into the formula. if anyone knows the simplest way of doing so, id really appreciate it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389264/how-to-get-the-separate-digits-of-an-int-number

Answer (score 1):

You can get each digit using a modulus operation.

In this case use base ten. 56 % 10 = 6. Then divide by 10 remove the last digit. 56/10 = 5 (because of integer division). Repeat for each digit.

Answer (score 0):

[String.split("")](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) will split a String into all its parts:

```
String input = "1234";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input.split("")));
// output: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```