# How can I Partition the number in an EditText?

Tags: java, android

I want to Partition the input number to use its ciphers.
For example, I have an input number : 1563
How can I separate 1, 5, 6 and 3 and use them as separate integers?

```
package todicemal;

public class um {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int k=1563;
        System.out.println(k);
    }

}
```

How can I use the parts of k which form 1563 and use every single cipher as an integer?

Comment: I agree this question isn't well researched as it has been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

```
Stack<Integer> list = new Stack<Integer>();    
while (k > 0) {
  list.push(k % 10);
  k /= 10;
}
```

Comment: That will give you the numbers in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks ,but how i can use every nomber ?

Comment: Thanks @BlackHatSamurai - answer updated

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389264/how-to-get-the-separate-digits-of-an-int-number) by jjnguy, you can just do:

```
int number; // = and int
LinkedList<Integer> stack = new LinkedList<Integer>();
while (number > 0) {
    stack.push( number % 10 );
    number = number / 10;
}

while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    print(stack.pop());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following

```
int value = 1563;
char[] charValue = String.valueOf(value).toCharArray();

for (char c: charValue) {
    int num = Character.getNumericValue(c);
    //Use num
}
```