# How to check if a number contains a certain digit?

Tags: java

I need to write a boolean method called `hasEight()`, which takes an `int` as input and returns true if the number contains the digit 8 (e.g., 18, 808).

I don't want to use the "String conversion method".

I've tried the below code, but that only checks for the last digit.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Verificare {

    public static boolean hasEight(int numarVerificat) {
        int rest = numarVerificat % 10;
        return rest == 8;
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Introduceti numarul pentru verificare: ");
        int numar = keyboard.nextInt();
        Verificare.hasEight(numar);
        System.out.println("Afirmatia este: " + Verificare.hasEight(numar));
    
        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? If so, you might want to tag it as such, show us what you've tried so far, and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the separate digits of an int number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389264/how-to-get-the-separate-digits-of-an-int-number)

Comment: What is the number `808`? Decimal right? So it's `8x10^2 + 0x10^1 + 8x10^0`. So; given that, how would you access each digit individually?

Comment: Seems more like an IQ puzzle than relevant homework. When would one ever need to know how to do this?

Comment: @BoristheSpider: But `0x10^1 == 17`.

Comment: @jsheeran no, it equals 0. `10^1 == 10`; `10 * 0 == 0`. Where did `17` come from?

Comment: Read it as "hexadecimal 10 xor 1".

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Please take a moment to review our [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want to use string conversion methods then i think this method can be used.

```
public bool hasEight(int number)
{
      while(number > 0)
      {
          if(number % 10 == 8)
              return true;

          number=number/10;
      }
      return false; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used your advice Uday.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below function.

```
boolean hasEight(int num) {
    int rem;
    while (num > 0) {
        rem = num % 10;
        if (rem == 8)
            return true;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In every iteration of the loop, last digit of the number is retrieved (remainder when divided by 10). If it is 8, *true* is returned. Else, number is divided by 10 (integer division so that last digit is removed) and another iteration is started. When all digits are checked (8 or not), number becomes 0 and loop stops.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used your advice @Krisha Teja

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static boolean hasEight(int numarVerificat)
    {
        while(numarVerificat > 0)
          {
              if(numarVerificat % 10 == 8)
                  break;
              numarVerificat=numarVerificat/10;
          }
          return (numarVerificat>0); 
    }
```