# Get separate digits from int in C#

Tags: c#, .net, int

I stumbled across this challenge when I needed to calculate a check number/digit from the individual digits of the number itself.

E.g. I have the number (`Int32`) `423594340` and I want a collection of integers like `4,2,3,5,9,4,3,0`.

I think it is better to not convert the given `int` into a `String` because of performance. 
**But how do you do that instead?**

Comment: Did you just both post and answer?...

Comment: @GiladGreen: SO encourages to make posts about problems you solved yourself (given it is useful and not a dupe).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - Agree on that.. but getting all digits from an int... This has been asked so many times. I remember seeing one new question like this somewhere the last week or two

Comment: @GiladGreen There are other ways to post a good solution for a problem instead of asking a question and answering it at the same time ;)

Comment: @MightyBadaboom I honestly did not find another question for C#. Now, I agree with you and marked it as duplicate, too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I came up with an individual puzzled out solution.

### #1: Own created solution

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetDigits(int source)
{
    int individualFactor = 0;
    int tennerFactor = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, source.ToString().Length));
    do
    {
        source -= tennerFactor * individualFactor;
        tennerFactor /= 10;
        individualFactor = source / tennerFactor;

        yield return individualFactor;
    } while (tennerFactor > 1);
}
```

### #2: Modulo with Linq's .Reverse()

After that I explored the Internet for other solutions and I came across one from the Java folks: [How to get the separate digits of an int number?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3389287/2380948)

The downside is that the order of integers in the collection is reversed. Here comes Microsoft's **Linq**.

How to call the method with `.Reverse()`.

```
...
GetDigits2(input).Reverse()
...
```

And the actual method.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetDigits2(int source)
{
    while (source > 0)
    {
        var digit = source % 10;
        source /= 10;
        yield return digit;
    }
}
```

### #3: Modulo with Stack's LIFO

What else could I do when I do not want to think about calling `.Revers()` after the method (`GetDigits2(int source)`)? So I use a variable inside the method, call .Reverse() on the variable and return its result instead.

Or something totally different: I remember the LIFO logic. In .NET you use the Stack class for that.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetDigits3(int source)
{
    Stack<int> digits = new Stack<int>();
    while (source > 0)
    {
        var digit = source % 10;
        source /= 10;
        digits.Push(digit);
    }

    return digits;
}
```

---

### Testing

I tested each method 10 million times and measured the number of tickes between start and end of the test.

**#1: Own Created method**

```
1'549'084 ticks
```

**#2: Modulo with Linq's .Reverse()**

```
2'252'875 ticks
```

**#3: Modulo with Stack's LIFO**

```
23'626'839 ticks
```

---

**tl;dr**

Here comes the fiddle: [Get Digits from int](https://dotnetfiddle.net/teCO3f)

Comment: Posting a question you already solved just to post your own answer for getting reputation is not very sportmanslike...

Comment: @MightyBadaboom [It's perfectly fine](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)