# How to sort numbers in Android Studio?

Tags: java, modulo, modulus

How do I put each number in a variable, for example, I have 2118 and I want this:

**How do I do this if the number is unknown?**

```
int abcd = 2118;
int a = 8;
int b = 10;
int c = 100;
int d = 2000;
```

Or

```
int abcd = 2118;
int a = 8; // 8
int b = 1; // 10
int c = 1; // 100
int d = 2; //2000
```

Comment: what do you mean? because you already put your numbers in a variable

Comment: How do I do this if the number is unknown?

Comment: Will it always be 4 digits?

Comment: Not from 0-million

Comment: This does not seem a question based on android or android-studio but it is java-specific. There is no code example, so this is even not a technical question but you search a solution with no any tries. Can you at least provide a basic code of yours so that people can fix it?

Comment: Please try to do it yourself and ask a question about a specific problem you have with your code. If you don't know enough Java/don't have enough programming skills to do that, please learn Java/programming.

Comment: I did not write the code in this regard because I do not know how to begin
But to clarify:
The user may enter a number that is perhaps 0 and possibly greater than one million and want to sort the number according to each number in a variable

Comment: @kaaed you want to break the number down into ones, tens, hundreds etc... correct?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389264/how-to-get-the-separate-digits-of-an-int-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the modulus operator to do what (I think) you are asking.

Something like this...

```
 int num=1351280;
 int ones = (num % 10)/1;
 int tens = (num-ones) % 100;
 int hun = (num-(tens+ones)) % 1000;
 int thou = (num-(tens+ones+hun)) % 10000;
 int tenThou = (num-(tens+ones+hun+thou)) % 100000;
 int hunThou = (num-(tens+ones+hun+thou+tenThou)) % 1000000;
 int mil  = (num-(tens+ones+hun+thou+tenThou+hunThou)) % 10000000;

 System.out.println(mil);
 System.out.println(hunThou);
 System.out.println(tenThou);
 System.out.println(thou);
 System.out.println(hun);
 System.out.println(tens);
 System.out.println(ones);
```

This gives:

```
1000000 (Millions)
300000  (Hundred thousands)
50000   (Ten thousands)
1000    (Thousands)
200     (Hundreds)
80      (Tens)
0       (Ones)
```

The modulus operator gives you the remainder so 30 % 8 = 6 which is something like (30/8) = 3.  And 30-(3*8) = 6;

Comment: Thank you very much already solved my problem and learned something new from you
Thank you from my heart .

Answer (score 0):

Do you can convert to String then use String#toCharArray() and finally do a reverse loop.

```
String num = String.valueOf(someInt);
char[] dig = num.toCharArray();
char[] reverse = new char[dig.length()];
int j = 0;
for(int i=reverse.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    reverse[j] = dig[i];
    j++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer calculating digits recursively;

#### Sample Code

```
package com.levo.so.digits;

public class DigitDisplay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 2118;

        System.out.println("Number : " + number);
        System.out.println();

        int[] digits = getDigitArray(number);


        System.out.println("Digits;");
        System.out.println("-------");
        for(int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Digit [%d]: %d\n", i, digits[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("\n");

        System.out.println("Components");
        System.out.println("----------");
        for(int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("[%d]: %d\n", i, digits[i]*(int)Math.pow(10, i));
        }
    }

    private static int[] getDigitArray(int number) {
        int[] array = new int[getDigitCount(number)];

        int index = 0;
        while(number != 0) {
            array[index++] = (number%10);
            number /= 10;
        }

        return array;
    }

    private static int getDigitCount(int number) {
        int digitCount = 0;

        while(number != 0) {
            number /= 10;
            digitCount++;
        }

        return digitCount;
    }

}
```

#### Output

```
Number : 2118

Digits;
-------
Digit [0]: 8
Digit [1]: 1
Digit [2]: 1
Digit [3]: 2


Components
----------
[0]: 8
[1]: 10
[2]: 100
[3]: 2000
```