# Not sure how this extractDigits method works?

Tags: java

The person must create a while loop to  create an algorithm extractDigits that prints the individual digits of an integer. Ex) extractDigits(123) outputs "3", "2", "1".

I am not sure why exactly this method is correct and able to return each digit.

```
while(num > 0)
       {
            System.out.println(num % 10);
            num = (num/10);
        }
```

Comment: What you think it should be? Debug the code and then you will understand it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the separate digits of an int number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389264/how-to-get-the-separate-digits-of-an-int-number)

Comment: Take pen and paper and dry run through the loop, you will know.

Answer (score 0):

The modulus operator % returns the remainder of the two numbers after division

`In excel MOD(123,10) = 3` similarly in java `123 % 10 = 3`

then

when you divide `(123/10) = 12` and loop continues until `num=0`

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful replies! My mistake was I forgot that when it divides by ten, it gets rid of the remainder and assigns a new value without it. Than it just repeats.