# How to print each number of a given number separately?

Tags: java, while-loop, module, public

I have a code is written that is supposed to print each of the numbers separately. Heres an example.

```
printDigits(1362) prints
2
6
3
1

printsDigits(985) prints
5
8
9
```

You can pull apart a number into its digits using  `/ 10` and `% 10`.

I have started some code the way I was taught but I am not sure what to do with the other variables.
Please have a look:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(printDigits(1362));
    System.out.println(printDigits(985));
    }

  public static int printDigits(int x){
    int y = x % 10;
    while (x > 0){
      x = y;
      System.out.println(x);
      x = x / 10;
    }
   return x;
   }
}
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: @roxxy what is your question exactly?

Comment: `int y = x % 10;` needs to be inside the loop. Get rid of `x = y` and change `System.out.println(x)` to `System.out.println (y)`

Comment: Also why are you doing `return x`?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you convert the parameter x to String then read each Char in the String since a String is array of Char. If the output must be an int you convert the Char to int.

Comment: This is best I think

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `int y = x % 10;` inside the loop to "pull apart" every digit and print the digit `y` you have "pulled out".
Remove the `System.out.println` around your function calls.
You don't need to return a number, so you can change your return type to `void`:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printDigits(1362);
        System.out.println();
        printDigits(985);
    }

    public static void printDigits(int x) {
        while (x > 0) {
            int y = x % 10;
            System.out.println(y);
            x = x / 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `void` method returning a value?

Comment: It is not returnig a value. The function is already printing the numbers. So you don't need to.

Comment: Then what is `return x` doing here?

Answer (score 0):

`printDigits` method should be like this:

```
public static void printDigits(int x) {
    int y;
    while (x > 0) {
        y = x % 10;
        System.out.println(y);
        x = x / 10;
    }
}
```

And the calling of the method will be like this:

```
printDigits(1362); // without the System.out.println()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to achieve such results. You can better understand all solutions in these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389264/how-to-get-the-separate-digits-of-an-int-number).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void printDigits(int num) {
    while(num>0) {
        int remainder = num%10;
        num = num/10;
        System.out.println(remainder);
        printDigits(num);
    }

}
```

You can use recursion to make it even more efficient.