# How to design a function that prints out specific digits of a number

Tags: java, recursion

Example:

Input:

```
140
```

Output:

```
1 4 0
```

I wanted to make it divide by 100 so that the outcome will be 1, and then divide by 10 and the outcome will be 4 and then by 1 and the answer will be 0. But I am not sure how I am able to achieve it. I also want to use recursion in the method.

Comment: You should add what have you tried until now?

Comment: Hint: it is easier to extract the last digit instead of the first.

Comment: It might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389264/how-to-get-the-separate-digits-of-an-int-number

Comment: Hint: beware negative numbers

Answer (score 1):

You can see an int as a String

```
int n = 140;
String s = String.valueOf(n);
for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
    System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
}
```

With no need of recursion.

With recursion it could be something like (i haven't tried it so it could not work):

```
public String separateInteger(int n){
   if(n < 10){
       return String.valueOf(n);
   }
   else{ 
       int mod = n%10;
       int quot = n/10;
       return String.valueOf(mod) + separateInteger(quot);
   }
}
```

I hope have answered your question. :)