# Splitting int number

Tags: split, printing

How can I split an int number with out using string, for example for the number 123456 and 2 splits i should print = 12|34|56

for 1234567 and 3 splits I should print = 1|234|567
from right to left
Sincerely.

Comment: Is it not possible to convert to a string, and then back into an int?

Comment: hint: `123456 % 100 == 56`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mod operator with powers of 10 to get remainders

similar question answered here:
[How to get the separate digits of an int number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389264/how-to-get-the-separate-digits-of-an-int-number)