# Reverse Array Order

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

I am trying to reverse the order of an Array in java.
What is the most efficient way to do so in O(n) with the least amount of memory used.
No need to answer with code, pseudo code will be fine.
Here is my thought process:

```
  create a new temp array //I think this is a waste of memory, 
                          //but I am not sure if there's a better way
 grab elements from the end of the original array -decrement this variable
 insert element in beginning of temp array -increment this variable
then make the original array point to the temp array? //I am not sure 
            //if I can do this in java; so let's say the 
            //original array is Object[] arr; and the temp array is 
            //Object[] temp. Can I do temp = arr; ?
```

Is there a better more efficient way to do this perhaps without using a temp array?
and Lastly, assume that there are no nulls in the array, so everything can work.
Thank you

Edit: no this is not homework.

Comment: Is this homework?  If yes, please tagged as such.

Comment: consider swaping first and last items and then the second and second last items till you reach half the list... you will just need one temporary variable and will still go over the list once?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java

Comment: Can you use the java lib? `Collections.reverseOrder()`

Comment: Just loop through the original array in reverse order, and create a new container to contain the new order inserts. it's O(n)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If it's an Object array, then `Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(array))` will do the job with constant memory and linear time -- no temporary array required.

Comment: +1 Indeed, since the OP now says this is not homework, this is a great answer.

Comment: Love the solution. Just confirmed that no temporary array is required see: http://ideone.com/api/embed.js/link/xLLTpl ... click "Clone" and then "Run"

Comment: Does not work, at least with Java 1.6:
System.out.println( X[ 0 ] + " to " + X[ X.length - 1 ] );
   Collections.reverse( Arrays.asList( X ) );
   System.out.println( X[ 0 ] + " to " + X[ X.length - 1 ] );
prints:
2272.6270739116 to 186.704625250768
2272.6270739116 to 186.704625250768

Comment: @Jean-Yves: What is the type of `X`?  I strongly suspect it's not an object array, which I specified in my answer was necessary.

Answer (score 13):

Use a single temp element.

```
int array[SIZE];
int temp;

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE/2; i++)
  {
     temp = array[i];
     array[i] = array[SIZE-1 - i];
     array[SIZE-1 - i] = temp;
  }
```

Answer (score 12):

You don't need to use a temporary array; just step through the array from the beginning to half-way through, swapping the element at `i` for the element at `array.length-i-1`. Be sure the handle the middle element correctly (not hard to do, but do make sure.)

Answer (score 2):

you can do it without needing a temp array

- loop from the beginning (or end doesn't matter) to the middle of the array
- swap element with element at (last element - index) (so 0 and `size - 1`, 1 and `size - 2` etc)
- you'll do something like this to swap:

```
    temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[end-i];
    a[end-i] = temp;
```

- repeat

Answer (score 0):

Here's two solutions:

```
    loop to N/2
      swap each element at i with element at N - i
```

Another solution is (depending on your circumstances) fake reversing the array by indexing:

```
    GetValueAt(int i){return array[N - i];}
```

Answer (score -1):

Lets consider we have Integer array
arr[] - Integer array.

```
for(int i=0,int J=arr.length-1 ; i<j ; i++,j--)
{
    temp =a[i];
    a[i]=a[j];
    a[j]=temp;
 }
```

this algorithm has O(n/2) as we will perfrom n/2 swaps. and its space complexity is constant 1 , as we are taking on temp variable.

Answer (score -2):

pseudocode, assuming 0-based-index arrays:

```
for i in range(0, len(array)/2):
     swap(array[i], array[(len(array)-1)-i])
```

Comment: This does not look like Java.

Answer (score -2):

You can Do this in just two steps

```
ArrayList<Element> YourTempElement= new ArrayList<Element>(mElements);
Collections.reverse(YourTempElement);
```

Comment: Uses same methods as accepted answer, just less elegantly and with less of an explanation.

Comment: there are no need of explanation bro it's little two step nd i'm not explainer.

Comment: Good answers on Stack Overflow explain things. The accepted answer does. If there's already a good answer that says the same thing you would, or if there's no way to write a good answer at all, there's no real point in adding an answer to the question: that just adds noise.