# Sorting an int array in descending order is giving "method not applicable for arguments"

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to sort an array in descending order in Java using this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   Comparator comparator = Collections.reverseOrder();
   Arrays.sort(arr,comparator);
}
```

But I get this error:

> The method sort(int[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (int[], Comparator)

Comment: Have you looked at the Arrays API?

Comment: Make your array of type `Integer`. Arrays.sort don't accept Comparator for primitive type.. Have a look at various methods of [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you're trying to loop, but the `Arrays.sort` methods operating on *primitive* arrays don't allow a custom comparator to be specified.

The simplest approach would be to sort and then reverse the array. I can't immediately find a `reverse` method which would take an `int[]` but it would be easy to write your own.

Answer (score 8):

If you look at the [javadoc of Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), you will see that the only `sort` methods that take a `comparator` as a second parameter are:

```
sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
sort(T[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

In your case, `int[]` is not a `T[]` (`Integer[]` would be) so you can't apply those methods.

You have (at least) 2 options:

- sort in ascending order and [reverse the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995432/reverse-array-order)
- transform the array into an `Integer[]` and use the methods above

Answer (score 1):

Change int Integer while defining an array.
Change `int arr[]={};` to `Integer arr[]={};`
This will make your code to run

Comment: Primitive type array is not the only problem. Here is also calling sort() in a cycle.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.sort(arr,comparator);` will not work on primitives. The `arr` has to be array of Objects.

Answer (score 0):

The only sort method that accepts a comparator in the Arrays class requires you to supply an object array.  There is no method within the class with a signature of sort(int[], Comparator)