# Java comparator for sorting not working

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Default sort method is not working for me in Java.

```
    int[] nums = {11,14,15,10}; 
    Arrays.sort(nums, new Comparator<Integer>() {

    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        // compare code here
    }
});
```

The error I get is

```
"The method sort(int[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (int[], new Comparator<Integer>(){})"
```

I feel like I am stupid now.

Comment: An `int[]` is not an `Integer[]`, and an `int` is not an `Integer`.

Comment: You can not specify Comparator to sort int[] by `Arrays.sort`.

Comment: Perhaps more specifically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654600/descending-order. Assume someone in the world has had the same problem as you at some point in the past and work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *no* way to use `Arrays.sort` to sort an `int[]` with any ordering other than the default.  You can sort an `Integer[]` with an arbitrary `Comparator`, but there is no way to customize sorting for an `int[]`.