# Reverse method for Array<String>

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

I am trying to write a method which return the playing cards (`Array<String>`) in reverse order.

Each card is represented as a combination of : card values (A, 1-9, T, J,Q,K) and suits (h=hearts, d=diamonds, c=clubs, s=spades) also 10 is always represented by T not by 10 as two characters.

How to write a reverse method for `Array<String>` in Java?

```
public Array<String> reverseDeck(Array<String> deckOfCards) { 

}
```

Comment: 1) See [Starting Writing a Program](http://home.earthlink.net/~patricia_shanahan/beginner.html) for great tips. 2) [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.

Comment: 1) search google for "reverse array java" 2) click the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995432/reverse-array-order 3) follow the instructions there.

Comment: @AndrewThompson it is protected now. As in, not visible from outside. Why did you remove it?

Comment: @Baadshah Oh write.  You're welcome.  :)

Comment: @JanDvorak As in, not visible from outside. Why did you remove it? what does it mean ?

Comment: @Baadshah "not visible from the outside" - I was referring to the meaning of `protected` in Java and the lack of the tag in the title. "why did you remove it?" - I was referring to the removal of the tag from the title. I see no reason to remove "in Java" (as opposed to "[java] how do I..." or "java - how do I...")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public ArrayList<String> reverseDeck(ArrayList<String> deckOfCards)
{
   ArrayList<String> reversedDeck = new ArrayList<String>(deckOfCards.size());

   for(int i=deckOfCards.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
       reversedDeck.add(deckOfCards.get(i));

   return reversedDeck;
}
```