# Improving performance with a array of million records

Tags: java, string

I do have a array with million String objects..

```
ex:String values [] = new String[10000000]
```

and I've to reverse all the elements and what is the best way of doing it to improve performance?

Comment: You can only *improve* performance if you have something to measure it against. Please post your current code.

Comment: It'll be O(n) in any case.

Comment: Code a really bad way to do it.  Then make it better ... and way you will have improved performance :-)

Comment: The obvious solution where swap elements starting from the ends and moving to the middle should be optimal, I think.  No, I ain't gunna code it for you!

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9995432/869736

Comment: Creating another array and copying elements in reverse order may not be the optimal solution. You can create `reverse view` of your original array, without actually copying it. This view may be represented by `Iterable` that wraps your original array and creates iterators that traverse it in reverse order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making you task harder than it needs to be by not using the Collections standard library. Instead of an array use a List then use the standard Collections.reverse() method.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(values);
Collections.reverse(list);
```