# Reversing integer array

Tags: java

Just curious, but when I try to use this to reverse an array it always spits out some incoherent gibberish instead of the array reversed, such as `[I@43256ea2`. Any ideas as to why it does this?

```
public class Fiddle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] number = {1,2,3,4,5};
        System.out.println(reverse(number));
    }
    public static int[] reverse(int[] a) {
        int[] b = new int[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            b[a.length-1-i] = a[i];
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any ideas as to why this is happening (it's probably because I'm forgetting something though).

Comment: your printing binary information. You'll need to convert each entry in the array to ascii before your print.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java

Comment: Agreed -- but not immediately obvious to me why an array of {5,4,3,2,1} in memory would resolve to "[I@43256ea2". I'm imagining the bytes "00 00 00 05 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 03 etc...". Can anyone shed some light on why we see this specific output string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the utility method [`java.util.Arrays.toString(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverse(number)));
```

Array classes do not override `Object.toString()`, meaning they use [the default implementation provided by Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), which is "`type@hashcode_in_hex`".  The String representation of the type `int[]` is `[I`, which is why you are seeing this "incoherent gibberish."

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverse(number)));
```

It's one of the "mistakes" of java - you have to use `Arrays.toString()` otherwise you get the default `toString()` from `Object`, which produces output like you're seeing,

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the hash of the array. you should do something like

```
for(int i: reverse(number)){
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Commons.lang

```
ArrayUtils.reverse(int[] array)
```

Done.