# Reverse order of single dimensional array in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reverse an int array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java)

I need to reverse the order of the given numbers in the array without using a temp.

```
public class Reverse 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int[] num  = { 12, 34, 50, 67, 88 }, cl, cl2;

        for (i=0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            cl = a[i];
            cl2 = a[(a.length - 1 )-1];
            System.out.println (cl1 + " " + cl2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Print array elements from upper-bound to lower-bound index.

Comment: Impossible.  A register is a "temp", and you need a register just to address the array.

Comment: @AVD - But how do you index the array without a temp?

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java

Comment: StackExchange != DoMyHomework.

Comment: @spyder, please camel case your variables ;)

Comment: @mre or adding parentheses. May be they are methods ;)

Answer (score 5):

Since it only seems that you're printing the values out, you can iterate over your array backwards.

```
for(int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // relevant code here
}
```

Comment: I was about to add this code fragment. Cool :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`Collections#reverse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29) to inline a reverse sort of the integer array,

```
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(num));
```

Comment: ... as long as you've already covered Collections prior to this homework assignment ;)

Answer (score 1):

The answers given are perfect. But i just added another answer in case if you want to store the reverse array into the original array without using any temp. use this.

```
public class Reverse 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int[] a = { 12, 34, 50, 67, 88 };
        int i, j;

        for (i = 0, j = a.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
       {
           a[i]=a[i]+a[j];
           a[j]=a[i]-a[j];
           a[i]=a[i]-a[j];
       }
    }
}
```