# Program to reverse an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to invert an array, with the below-shown code, with no sucess. The output of the program is `7,0,0` and not `7,1,2` as its supposed to be.

Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ReverseArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] data = {1, 2, 7};
        int[] dataR = reverseArray(data);
        System.out.println("Original Array: " + Arrays.toString(data));
        System.out.println("Reverse Array: " +  Arrays.toString(dataR));
    }
    public static int[] reverseArray(int[] data)
    {
        int[] reversedData = new int[data.length];
        int i;
        for(i=0; i < data.length; i++);
        {
            reversedData[i] = data[(data.length - i -1)];
        }
        return reversedData;
    }
}
```

All help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you required to do it by hand?  Can you use something like `Collections.reverse(Collections.toArray(data)).toArray(new int[data.length])` ?

Comment: @BheshGurung I did say "something like" :P - trying to ascertain if it was homework or not ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
for(i=0; i < data.length; i++);
```

Delete the `;` . The way you wrote it, first there's a loop that counts `i` up to `data.length`, then a scoped block that tries to access `reversedData[data.length]` exactly once. That won't fly.

Funny thing: originally, probably none of us saw what the problem is; using formatting rules in an IDE will tell you pretty quickly what's wrong: you'll see that your code doesn't look like it's supposed to when formatted according to rules you're used to.

Comment: It also needs to stop half way to data.length or it reverses the array then unreverses it :P

Comment: @Patashu: No, it is building a new array, not swapping.

Comment: Ah, my mistake for skimming :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use temporary variable to swap values in array. For example like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < validData.length / 2; i++)
{
    int temp = validData[i];
    validData[i] = validData[validData.length - i - 1];
    validData[validData.length - i - 1] = temp;
}
```

or

```
ArrayUtils.reverse(int[] array)
```

All described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java) question.

Comment: Ehem, he isn't swapping anything, he's building a brand new array.

Answer (score 0):

Good catch, G. Bach. I'm also not sure about the first part of your question. It looks like the original array is `1, 2, 7`. Wouldn't the reverse of that be `7, 2, 1` and NOT `7, 1, 2`?

That said, it seems like you might be slowing things down by accessing `data.length` every time. I'd probably create a local variable thusly:

```
public static int[] reverseArray(int[] data)
{
    int arr_length = data.length
    int[] reversedData = new int[arr_length];
    int j = arr_length - 1;
    for(int i=0; i < arr_length; i++);
    {
        reversedData[i] = data[j--];
    }
    return reversedData;
}
```

Notice how `j` is automatically decremented after it's been accessed, keeping things nice and tidy. Also, we've saved the length of the array into a local variable so it's more efficient to access.

Comment: Just let the JVM's JIT handle it. ('sides, you're still accessing `data.length` each time in the `i < data.length`).

Comment: Oh yeah, because the length could have changed during the body of the loop, and so it would have to check. Good point. ^^;

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        int size=in.nextInt();
        int array[]=new int[size];

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            array[i]=in.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i=size-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
        }


        }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class ReverseArray 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        System.out.println("Enter the array Size");
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        int size=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the array Elements");
        int array[]=new int[size];

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            array[i]=in.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("reverse of entered are given below for Size : " +size );
        for(int i=size-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
        }


        }

}
```

Comment: Please also add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Input:**

Enter the number of values to reverse
7

1 2 3 4 6 7 8

**Output:**
Reversed Array :[8, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 1]

Reversed Array :[8, 7, 3, 4, 6, 2, 1]

Reversed Array :[8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1]

**Coding:**

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){

         System.out.println("Enter the number of values to reverse");

         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

         int n  = sc.nextInt();
         int num[] = new int[n];    
         for(int i=0; i < num.length; i++) 
             num[i] = sc.nextInt();

         reverseArray(num, n-1);

    }

    private static void reverseArray(int num[], int end) {
        int start = 0;
        int temp;

        while(start < end) {
            temp = num[start];
            num[start] = num[end];
            num[end] = temp;
            start++;
            end--;
            System.out.println("Reversed Array :"+ Arrays.toString(num));

        }


    }


}
```