# How to reverse an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Need a method that returns the array with the order of the numbers reversed.

For example, if the input array is
{5,6,8}
the method returns {8,6,5}

This is what I have done. I get an error message saying temp cannot be resolved.

```
public int[] reverseData (int[] validData) {

for(int i = 0; i < validData.length; i++)
{
int temp = validData[i];
validData[i] = validData[validData.length - i - 1];
validData[validData.length - i - 1] = temp;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java

Comment: change `i < validData.length` to `i < validData.length/2`

Comment: @thegrinner: It's in the title.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was hoping for something more specific, like "But it throws error X" or "Input X gives me output Y, which is wrong."

Comment: @thegrinner: If we required all questions to be of that form, there wouldn't be any useful information on Stack Overflow at all, but only endless parades of "help me solve my highly-localized problem" questions (we're almost at that point now).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I hadn't thought of it that way. My concern was in the opposite direction - fear that it was too vague (like "How do I use library XYZ").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only do that for half of the array. If you swap each pair twice, you'll end up with the exact same array. So, use

```
 for(int i = 0; i < validData.length/2; i++)
```

instead