# Issues with reversing an array

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

```
public static void reversedArray(double testArray[])
{
    double lastNumber = 0;
    for (int counter1 = 0, counter2 = testArray.length - 1; counter1 < testArray.length; counter1++, counter2 \--)
    {
       lastNumber = testArray[counter2];
       testArray[counter1] = testArray[counter2];
       testArray[counter2] = lastNumber;
    }
}
```

This is the method that reverses the array. The array is a length of 5. It correctly displays the first 3 numbers, but the last 2 numbers are wrong. E.g., I enter 1,2,3,4,5 and it returns 5,4,3,4,5

Edit: Looks like I got it, I took out the testArray.length as the comparison in the for loop and replaced it with counter2.

Comment: What language is this? I'm inclined to say Java, but am only 99% sure.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2137755/1817029

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting data in your array. You need some temporary location to store it. Now you should be able to fix your method yourself.

Next time consider to use `Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(yourArray))` instead of writing it by your own.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
  lastNumber = testArray[counter2];
  testArray[counter2] = testArray[counter1];
  testArray[counter1] = lastNumber;
```

Comment: no, it shouldn't be like that. have you checked your answer?

Comment: Indeed I have not. That's not the only issue with his code, but certainly one issue.