# Why won't this reverse the array?

Tags: java

I thought about it, tried different things for about an hour but couldn't come up with anything. I didn't want to post here because I wanted to figure it out myself but there's just something i'm not getting

```
class Exercise5
{
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
int[] val = {0, 1, 2, 3}; 
int temp;

System.out.println( "Original Array: " 
    + val[0] + " " + val[1] + " " + val[2] + " " + val[3] );

// reverse the order of the numbers in the array
for( temp = 0; temp < val.length; temp++) {

    val[temp] = val[3 - temp];


}



System.out.println( "Reversed Array: " 
    + val[0] + " " + val[1] + " " + val[2] + " " + val[3] );
 }
}
```

It' prints out 3 2 2 3 with every different strategy i've tried

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reverse an int array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java)

Comment: Try running this algorithm, very literally, by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

temp = 0

```
val[0] =val[3];
```

temp =1

```
val[1] =val[2];
```

temp =2

```
val[2] =val[1];
```

temp =3

```
val[3] =val[0];
```

**Solution:**

Use another array to hold reversed values or swap two values at a time using a temporary variable (0 & 3, 1&2)

Comment: You nailed it. Plus one. Adding some description would make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

```
for( temp = 0; temp < val.length; temp++) {
    val[temp] = val[3 - temp];
}
```

What this does is this;

```
val = [0, 1, 2, 3]

val[0] = val[3]
=> val = [3, 1, 2, 3]

val[1] = val[2]
=> val = [3, 2, 2, 3]

val[2] = val[1]
=> val = [3, 2, 2, 3]

val[3] = val[0]
=> val = [3, 2, 2, 3]
```

What you want to do is loop the index through half the array and *swap* the low and high value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// reverse the order of the numbers in the array
for( temp = 0; temp < val.length/2; temp++) {
    int tmp = val[temp];
    val[temp] = val[3 - temp];
    val[3 - temp] = tmp;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use another array. You are changing the value of the original before you want to. Or if the length is even you can swap them

Comment: You can swap them in place without another array, even if the length is odd. Just don't swap the middle item (or swap it with itself, which is a no-op).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

val[temp] = val[3 - temp];

only assigns the value of val[3-temp] into val[temp], it does not swap them. If you want to swap them, you need to use a temporary variable.

Second,

You only need to iterate halfway through the array, not all the way through it.

Answer (score 0):

val[temp] = val[3 - temp];

when temp =0

val[0]= val[3-0]
val[0] = val[3]= 3

when temp =1

val[1]= val[3-1]
val[1] = val[2]= 2

when temp =2

val[2]= val[3-2]
val[2] = val[1]= 2 (previous step you can see val[1]=2)

when temp =3

val[3]= val[3-3]
val[3] = val[0]= 3

result 3 2 2 3

Answer (score 0):

This line is culprit inside the for loop:

```
val[temp] = val[3 - temp];
```

Let's go over the iteration to see what it's doing.

1. val[0] = val[3]    ->  3,1,2,3
2. val[1] = val[2]    ->  3,2,2,3
3. val[2] = val[1]    ->  3,2,2,3
4. val[3] = val[0]    ->  3,2,2,3

Answer (score 0):

Most of the people have given you the analysis. This is what you can do to resolve.

Declare one more int array

```
int[] val = {0, 1, 2, 3}; 
int temp;
int[] reverseVal = new int[val.length];
```

Add to reversed values to this array

```
for( temp = 0; temp < val.length; temp++) {

    reverseVal [temp] = val[val.length - temp];

}
```

Comment: There's no need for a second array.

Comment: @DavidConrad, then what do you suggest.. Swap a pair of values in the same array?

Comment: Yes, of course. Use a single temporary int variable, you can swap them pairwise from the ends towards the middle. It's a very common idiom for reversing an array in place, I've found.