# How do I reverse my array to print out the array in reverse?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
public class BubbleSort {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        int[] values = {45, 67, 12, 34, 25, 39};
        int pass, comparison, temp;
        String results = "";

        for (pass = 1; pass <= values.length - 1; pass++) {
            for (comparison = 1; comparison <= values.length - pass; comparison++) {
                if (values[comparison - 1] > values[comparison]) {
                    temp = values[comparison - 1];
                    values[comparison - 1] = values[comparison];
                    values[comparison] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
             results += values[i] + "\n";
        }
        System.out.print(results);
    }
}
```

That's my code. It prints out:
12
25
34
39
45
67

How do I reverse it so it prints out:

67
45
39
34
25
12

Also, how do I just print the array out normally like:

45
67
12
34
25
39

I'm stuck on how to print them out.

Comment: Redundant titles are redundant.

Comment: This explains how to reverse an array of type int in java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You have to revert it on your own. there is not method out of the box that does this for you.

```
for(int i = 0; i < values.length / 2; i++)
{
    int temp = values[i];
    values[i] = values[values.length - i - 1];
    values[values.length - i - 1] = temp;
}
```

If you want to print the originial values of the array you must copy it, before you modify it.

Answer (score 0):

for reverse:

```
for (int i = values.length; i >= 0; i--) results += values[i] + "\n";
```

for original you need to copy the origina array first before processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it several ways but reversing the array is not necessary to print it reversed...

```
results = "";
for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) results = results+" "+values[i];
System.out.println("Non reversed :" + results);
results = "";
for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) results = values[i]+" "+results;
System.out.println("Reversed :" + results);
```

Now if you really want to reverse your array you just have to exchange values both by both, first and last, second and before-last, etc. up to the middle :

```
for (int i=0 i<values.length/2; i++) {
  int tmp = values[i];
  values[i] = values[values.length-1-i];
  values[values.length-1-i] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
public class BubbleSort
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        String results = "";
        int[] values = {45, 67, 12, 34, 25, 39};
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) results += values[i] + "\n";
        System.out.print(results);
        int pass, comparison, temp;
        results = "";
        for (pass = 1; pass <= values.length - 1; pass++)
        {
            for (comparison = 1; comparison <= values.length - pass; comparison++)
            {
                if (values[comparison - 1] > values[comparison])
                {
                    temp = values[comparison - 1];
                    values[comparison - 1] = values[comparison];
                    values[comparison] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) results += values[i] + "\n";
        System.out.print(results);
        results = "";
        for (int i = values.length; i >= 0; i--) results += values[i] + "\n";
        System.out.print(results);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in the Collections interface which reverses a List: [`Collections.reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29)

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(values); //Arrays.asList(45, 67, 12, 34, 25, 39);
Collections.reverse(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

For the print part remember that you have an array and [arrays are tricky to print](https://stackoverflow.com/q/409784/3735079). The list instead can be printed via `println` with no problems.