# Where did I go wrong in reversing an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

My Code:

```
public static int invertieren(int[] werte) {
    int[] werte1 = new int[werte.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < werte.length; i++) {
        for (int j = werte.length - 1; i < j; j--) {
            werte1[j] = werte[i];
        }
    }
    return werte1[0];
}
```

This is my code,
I developed a Method that should reverse my Array.
for example: in the main Method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int[] a = {1,2,3,4,7,5};
    System.out.println(invertieren(a));
}
```

and I need the that in position 0 - `werte1[0]` should give me `5` back.

```
werte1[0] = 5
werte1[1] = 7
werte1[2] = 4
```

my new Array should look like that: `int[] werte = {5,7,4,3,2,1}`

my quastion I have not been answered before, cause I'm asking about my code, to learn from making it right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reverse an int array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java)

Comment: Can you explain idea behind your code a little? How do you think it should work?

Comment: Tip: use only a single loop that increments i and decrements j on each iteration.

Comment: it should store the value of the first array(werte) in the secound (werte1) in the upside down order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need nested loops to reverse the array. You just need to loop through the arrays like this:

```
static int[] invertieren(int[] werte) {
    int[] werte1 = new int[werte.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < werte.length; i++) {
        werte1[i] = werte[werte.length - i - 1];
    }
    return werte1;
}
```

If you want to return the reversed array, you need to change the return type of your original method to return a `int[]` instead of a `int`, and then return `werte1` instead of `werte1[0]`.

To understand how this works assume that `werte.length == 6`. So for `i = 0` we have:

```
werte1[i] = werte[werte.length - i - 1]
werte1[0] = werte[6 - 0 - 1] = werte[5] = 5
```

For `i = 1`:

```
werte1[1] = werte[6 - 1 - 1] = werte[4] = 7
```

And so on. So we go through `werte1` from `0` to `5` storing the values from `werte` from `5` to `0`.

If you analise how `invertieren()` currently works you will see why the result is wrong:

```
Initial values:
    werte = {1,2,3,4,7,5}
    werte1 = {0,0,0,0,0,0}

for i = 0:
    for j from 5 to 1:
        werte1[j] = werte[0]

intermediate result: werte1 = {0,1,1,1,1,1}

for i = 1:
    for j fom 5 to 2:
        werte1[j] = werte[1]

intermediate result: werte1 = {0,1,2,2,2,2}

for i = 2:
    for j from 5 to 3:
        werte1[j] = werte[2]

intermediate result: werte1 = {0,1,2,3,3,3}

for i = 3:
    for j from 5 to 4:
        werte1[j] = werte[3]

intermediate result: werte1 = {0,1,2,3,4,4}

for i = 4:
    for j from 5 to 5:
        werte1[j] = werte[4]

final result: werte1 = {0,1,2,3,4,7}

for i = 5 it will do nothing, since j starts at 5.
```

It does not reverse the original array at all, so `werte1[0] == 0`.

Comment: I need actually to change it, that is right, but I set it as int cause I wanted to chick it if it does work...!!

Comment: What I don't get, why you did this : 
werte[werte.length - i - 1] ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static int[] invertieren(int[] werte){
    int[] werte1 = new int[werte.length];
    int length = werte.length-1;
    for(int i= 0; i < werte.length; i++){

            werte1[length-i] = werte[i];

        }
    return werte1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're incorrectly using a nested loop, use a single loop instead:

```
public int[] invertArray(int[] oldInts)
{
    int[] newInts = new int[oldInts.length];

    for (int i = oldInts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        newInts[oldInts.length - i - 1] = oldInts[i];
    }

    return newInts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for a class or for your own knowledge then this is not your answer.  Otherwise, I would use Apache Commons [ArrayUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html).  They have several overloaded reverse methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is working code with a modified `main` method:

```
public static int[] invertieren(int[] werte) {
    int[] werte1 = new int[werte.length];
    for (int i = 1; i <= werte.length; i++) {
        werte1[i - 1] = werte[werte.length - i];
    }
    return werte1;
}
```

Your modified `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 5};
    for (int revVal : invertieren(a)) {
        System.out.println(revVal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks as though you are returning the value at index 0.

```
public static int[] invertieren(int[] werte) {
    int[] werte1 = new int[werte.length];
    int len = werte.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        werte1[len-i] = werte[i];
    }
    return werte1;
}
```

Comment: what I did here, was that I started the werte array from positin 0 till werte.length and the werte1 from the end till 0 and saved the value of the positin i in j but in the upside down order.

Comment: It still doesn't work.  You're carrying forward logic errors from the question into your code (in this case the loop boundaries).  You need to test before you post.