# arranging arrays backward in java

Tags: java, arrays

So let's say I have an array called

```
char[] arr = new char[8];
```

and using a for loop i assign it all 0

```
for (int i = 0; i<8;i++)
{
     arr[i]='0';
}
```

and i have another array and lets say i have an array with

```
char[] reverseArr = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','Z'};
```

how do you assign it with reverse order of reverseArr to arr?
So i would have an array called arr with an element of Z G F E D C B A.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two variables on for statement and assign the last value of array to the first position on reverse array.

```
char[] reverseArr = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','Z'};
char[] arr = getReverseArray(reverseArr);

public char[] getReverseArray(char[] arrayToReverse) {
   char[] reverseArray = new char[arrayToReverse.length];
   for(int i = arrayToReverse.length - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
       reverseArray[j] = arrayToReverse[i];
   }
   return reverseArray;
}
```

By the way, you don't need to assign values to the char array to replace it. (You're assigning `'0'` to each array position);