# Basic Errors: Syntax error, insert } to complete ClassBody

Tags: java, syntax, brackets

Below is the starter code that my school gave me, and the error keeps persisting until I delete the reverse(int[], originalArray,) method. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here? (There's a test class given to us, but it's too long to post)

```
import java.util.*;
public class ReverseRecurse {

  public int[] initArray() {

  }

  public void printArray ( int[] array) {

  }

  public void reverse ( int [] originalArray, int low, int high) {

  }

  public int reverse ( int[] originalArray, ) {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `,` after `originalArray` parameter
also the function should return an array. If you have no array to return, then `return null`;

try this

`public int reverse ( int[] originalArray ) { return null; }`

**Full code :**

```
import java.util.*;
public class ReverseRecurse {

  public int[] initArray() {

  }

  public void printArray ( int[] array) {

  }

  public void reverse ( int [] originalArray, int low, int high) {

  }

  public int reverse ( int[] originalArray ) {
    return null;
  }

}
```

To implement the actual reverse function - Learn from this  : [How do I reverse an int array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters the

```
public int[] initArray() {

}
```

needs to have a return that would throw an error in itself.

it should be something like

```
public int[] initArray() {
    return someArray;
}
```