# Reversing elements in Arrays

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] HwArray = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < HwArray.length; i++) {
        HwArray[i] = i;
        }

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < HwArray.length; i++){
    HwArray[i] = (int) (100 + Math.random() * 100);         

    System.out.print("HwArray[i]=" + HwArray[i]);
            }

        }

    {
        int[] reverse(int[] HwArray); {
            int[] reversed = new int[HwArray.length];
            for (int i=0; i<HwArray.length; i++) {
                reversed[i] = HwArray[HwArray.length - 1 - i];
            }
            return reverse;
        }
    }

}
```

Sorry, I'm still learning. I'm trying to reverse the order of all the elements, but I keep receiving an error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This code is rife with errors.  Does it even compile?

Comment: *"I keep receiving an error"* What error? Compilation error because last line should be `return reversed;`, not `return reverse;`? Something else?

Comment: No. I get compilation error.

Comment: `int[] reverse(int[] HwArray); {` - that will not work

Comment: the code has syntax and compile errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reverse an int array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, you're actually not that far off. The `reverse` function actually seems to work okay but you have all kinds of weird syntax errors and you're not even calling the `reverse` method. Try doing this:

1. Move the `reverse` method inside the class where `main` is defined. If you want to call it directly from `main` you'll have to make it an static method.
2. Get rid of the extra curly braces on lines 17 and 25.
3. Remove the semicolon on line 18 when declaring `reverse`. It shouldn't be there.
4. The `reverse` method is trying to return a variable called `reverse`. That's the name of the method, you can't do that. I think you meant to return `reversed`.
5. Actually call the `reverse` method after you have initialized the array with random numbers. Then print the array out again to verify that it worked.
6. Notice that you're not actually printing out the values of the array on line 11. That should be `System.out.println("HwArray[" + i + "]=" + HwArray[i]);`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the conceptually easiest way to reverse the order of elements in an array is to swap each `ith` element in the first half of the array of size `N` with the `N-ith` element in the second half:

```
int[] reversed = new int[10];
for (int i=0; i < HwArray.length/2; ++i) {
    reversed[i] = HwArray[HwArray.length-1-i];
    reversed[HwArray.length-1-i] = HwArray[i];
}
```

**Demo here:**

## IDEOne

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors:

First of all, it should be `return reversed` instead of `return reverse`.

Then, you cannot define any method inside a method(here, method reverse is defined inside the main method)

Then, you can do one thing, remove the following two braces:
1: The opening brace just before `int[] reverse(int[] HwArray)`
2: The closing brace in the last line

Last, it should be `int[] reverse(int[] HwArray) {` instead of `int[] reverse(int[] HwArray); {`

Answer (score 0):

```
Comparator<Integer> comparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o2.compareTo(o1);
    }
};

// option 1
Integer[] array = new Integer[] { 11, 44, 4, 3, 123 };
Arrays.sort(array, comparator);

// option 2
int[] array2 = new int[] {11, 44, 4, 3, 123};
List<Integer>list = Ints.asList(array2);
Collections.sort(list, comparator);
array2 = Ints.toArray(list);

// option 3
List<Integer> integersList = Ints.asList(arr);
Collections.sort(integersList, Collections.reverseOrder());
```