# reverse element of the array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

I want to print the array in reverse order but I don't know why it's not working. I want to reverse them using the way I have mentioned below, in a single line, but my logic is not working.

```
void dynamicinputArraytwo() throws IOException  {

    int buffer;
    int i,jo,io;
    System.out.println("Enter size");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    buffer = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    float arrtwo[]=new float[buffer];

    for( i=0;i< arrtwo.length;i++){
        System.out.println ("Enter elements of array=");
        arrtwo[i] = Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
    }

    for (int jx=0; jx < arrtwo.length; jx++){
        System.out.println("array before reverse "+arrtwo[jx] + " ");
    }

    float arrthree[];
    arrthree = new float[arrtwo.length];

    for(io=0,jo=arrtwo.length; jo>=0;io++,jo--){
        arrthree[io] = arrtwo[jo] ;
    }

    for(io=0; io < arrtwo.length; io++){
        arrtwo[io] = arrthree[io] ;
    }

    for (int jx=0; jx < arrtwo.length; jx++){
        System.out.println("array after reverse "+arrtwo[jx] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reverse an int array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java)

Comment: Please be more specific about what's going wrong than "not working."

Comment: No i want to reverse array using the for loop mentioned in the program..i.e
 for(io=0,jo=arrtwo.length; jo>=0;io++,jo--){
        arrthree[io] = arrtwo[jo] ;
    }

Comment: And what is wrong with this loop...?

Comment: You should learn [how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: If you would please tell us precisely in what way your program is misbehaving, we would have a much greater chance of spotting in the code how the misbehaviour is coming about.

Comment: Did my suggestion fix the issue? If so, can you [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?

Comment: Yes it did @EJoshuaS

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is here:

```
for(io=0,jo=arrtwo.length; jo>=0;io++,jo--){
    arrthree[io] = arrtwo[jo] ;
}
```

The last index of an array is `length - 1` because arrays are indexed starting at 0, so you'll have an exception (i.e. `arrtwo[arrtwo.length]` is *not* a valid index in the array). You should set `jo` to `arrtwo.length - 1` initially instead.