# java | Return a reversed array by FOR loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, reverse

I am stuck with an exercise which tells me to create a reversed array from the given one.

After some thinking I made such code:

```
    public int[] reverse3(int[] nums) {

  int[] nums2 = new int[3];

  for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

     for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {

          nums2[j] = nums[i];

    }
  }
  return nums2;
}
```

But it is throwing out three exact same numbers.

Comment: Hint: you only need one loop for this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a nested for loop - just iterate over the source array and fill the result array in the opposite order:

```
public int[] reverse(int[] nums) {
    int len = nums.length;
    int[] result = new int[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        result[len - i - 1] = nums[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From a first look, your code should be more like this:

```
public int[] reverse3(int[] nums) 
{

  // initialize a second array with the same length
  int[] nums2 = new int[nums.length];
  // initialize the nums2 index
  int index = 0;

  // you only need one loop for this (since we'll be incrementing the index of nums2)
  for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     nums2[index] = nums[i];
     index++;
  }

  return nums2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swap the symetric values in the array like this :

```
 public static void reverse(int[] nums) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length / 2; i++) {
        int temp = nums[i];
        nums[i] = nums[nums.length - 1 - i];
        nums[nums.length - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To reverse an array you only have to swap the elements until the midpoint:

```
public int[] reverse(int[] nums) {
    int numsLength = nums.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < numsLength / 2; i++) {
        int temp = nums[i];
        nums[i] = nums[numsLength - i - 1];
        nums[numsLength - i - 1] = temp;
    }
    return nums;
}
```

This way is much more optimized.

[Source: How do I reverse an int array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

> I am new to Java development and sorry if this question will be too
>   silly, but it seems like I am stuck with the exercise which tells me
>   to create a reversed array from the given one.
>
> After some thinking I made such code:
>
> ```
>     public int[] reverse3(int[] nums) {
>
>   int[] nums2 = new int[3];
>
>   for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
>
>      for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
>
>           nums2[j] = nums[i];
>
>     }   }   return nums2; }
> ```
>
> But it is throwing out three exact same numbers. Could I please count
>   on some help? Thank you

Use one loop only. If you want to use 2 arrays(wich i do not see the point.) this will work:

```
    int j = 0;

    for(int i = nums.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
         nums2[j] = nums[i];
         j++;
     }
```

But if you want to use only one array, you can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length/2; i++) {
    int aux = nums[i];
    nums[i] = nums[nums.length-i-1];
    nums[nums.length-i-1] = aux;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many efficient ways to do it but to make you understand i am gonna modify your own code

public int[] reverse3(int[] nums) {

```
      int[] nums2 = new int[3];

      for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

         for (int j = (nums.length-1) - i; j < nums.length; j++) {

              nums2[j] = nums[i];

        }
      }

      return nums2;
    }
```

or let's do a a little bit modification rather than using nums.length() again and again we can put it inside a variable

public int[] reverse3(int[] nums) {

```
      int[] nums2 = new int[3];
      int length = nums.length;
      for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

         for (int j = (length-1) - i; j < length; j++) {

              nums2[j] = nums[i];

        }
      }

      return nums2;
    }
```

Remember it is not an efficient way but to make you understand i just modify the logic. Using nested loops like that will decrease the performance so better avoid it and try to do it in much more optimized way..