# Reversing ouput of string token

Tags: java, string, token, reverse

The following prints out the entered sentence in order.  I need it to print the input in reverse order:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Sentence {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
        String sentence = input.nextLine();

        String[] tokens = sentence.split(" ");
        System.out.println(tokens.length);

        for (String token : tokens) {
            System.out.println(token);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Please provide input and desired output.

Comment: The code I have now ask them to enter a sentence.  Lets say they enter "My name is Andrew", it prints out as                                               My                                                                                                              name                                                                                                          is                                                                                                                 Andrew

Comment: I need it to print                                                                                              Andrew                                                                                                           is                                                                                                                     name                                                                                                              My

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reverse an int array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular for loop and print from last index to first index:

```
for (int i = tokens.length-1; i>=0;i--) {
        System.out.println(tokens [i]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Much appreciated.  That gives me the output I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You're printing the tokens in the order of the sentence, in no way do you reverse it.
Try looping it in reverse

```
for(int i = tokens.length -1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  System.out.println(tokens[i]);
}
```

Comment: @Eritrean beat me to it.

Comment: `tokens.length` without brackets

Comment: You're right. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you both for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to reverse your sentence. It will print: sentence a is This

```
    String sentence = "This is a sentence";

    String[] tokens = sentence.split(" ");
    System.out.println(tokens.length);

    for (int i = tokens.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        System.out.print(tokens[i]);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
```