# Check if an array is palindrome

Tags: java, arrays, palindrome

I can't get to solution how to check if the array is mirrored

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int a=0 ;
    System.out.print("Array length:");
    int b= sc.nextInt();    
    int [] array = new int [b];
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++) {
        System.out.print("Type the number "+i+" element: ");
        a=sc.nextInt();
        array[i]=a;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    sc.close();
}
```

and when I type like for example Array length: 3 and my digits are 1 2 1

> Array length:3 
>   Type the number 0 element: 1
>   Type the number 1 element: 2
>   Type the number 2 element: 1
>   [1, 2, 1]

I get this in console , but now I don't know how to say if it is mirrored or not.

Comment: How would you, as a human, determine if that array is mirrored?

Comment: Start off by checking if the last and first element are equal... then 2nd and pre-last... until you meet up in center

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you compare the first array element to the last, the second to the penultimate, *etc*. until either you find a mismatch or you reach the middle.  Since the number of elements is not determined until runtime, you'll want to use a loop for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the array is palindrome by comparing it with reversed copy of the original array. Using [`ArrayUtils.reverse`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#reverse-int:A-) from Apache commons:

```
int[] arrCopy = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
ArrayUtils.reverse(arrCopy);
boolean isPalindrome = Arrays.equals(array, arrCopy);
```

See more [How do I reverse an int array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure about your definition of mirrored. But this will detect simmetric arrays. Hope it helps.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a=0 ;
        System.out.print("Array length:");
        int b= sc.nextInt();    
        int [] array = new int [b];
        for(int i=0;i<b;i++) {
            System.out.print("Type the number "+i+" element: ");
            a=sc.nextInt();
            array[i]=a;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

        int l = (b - b%2)/2;
        boolean mirrored = true;
        for(int i=0;i<l;i++) {
            if(array[i]!=array[array.length-1-i]) {
                mirrored = false;
                break;
            }
        }      
        if(mirrored) {
            System.out.println("The array is mirrored!! Fantastic.");
        }
        sc.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

made a small snippet if you are testing the code within main itself

```
int length = array.length;
boolean mirror = true;
for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    if(mirror) {
        int start = array[index];
        int end = array[--length];
        if (length < index) {
            break;
        }
        if (start != end) {
            mirror = false;
        }
    }
}
if(mirror) {
    System.out.println("is mirror");
}
else {
    System.out.println("is not mirror");
}
```