# Reversing array order in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to reverse the array order..but to no avail. **I understand that there are existing methods**, but i do not understand why mine does not work?
When i try to reverse Array of [1,2] i get [2,2], when trying [1,2,3] i get a reverse array of [3,2,3] instead. I cannot see what is wrong with my method..please help thanks!

```
      public static void reverseArray(int[] arr) {
        int j = arr.length-1;
        int [] temp = arr;

        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
          arr [i] = temp [j];
          j--;
        }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reverse an int array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

`temp` points to **the same array** as arr, so the array you're copying into is the same array you're copying out of. Your loop is equivalent to this:

```
int j = arr.length-1;

for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  arr [i] = arr[j];
  j--;
}
```

(note `arr` in both the source and the destination)

Either swap the array elements on every iteration, or have `temp` be a **copy** of arr:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) {
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[arr.length - 1 - i];
    arr[arr.length - 1 - i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: how do i modify in such a way that it then can be reversed?

Comment: @Jey.L I've added example code with a swap operation.

Answer (score 1):

That is because Java works with references, so when you assign **temp = arr** you are not duplicating the array, you are just creating another reference to the same array.
That way, when you edit the array **arr** you are also editing the array **temp**.

Try this instead:

```
public static void reverseArray(int[] arr) {
    int[] temp = new int[arr.length];

    for (int i = 0,j = arr.length - 1; i < arr.length; i++,j--) {
      temp[i] = arr[j];
    }
    arr = temp;
  }
```