# i am a beginner in coding how to return a 2D array with desired output

Tags: java, arrays

Given an *n* × *n* binary matrix image, flip the image horizontally, then invert it, and return the resulting image.

[image]

```java
class Solution {
    public int[][] flipAndInvertImage(int[][] image) {
        for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
            for (int j = image[0].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                image[i][j] ^= 1;
                System.out.printf("%d ", image[i][j]);
            }
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

This is my approach but when I return the 2D array not getting the desired output but you can see the stdout is printing result. May I know where I am going wrong

Comment: You haven't reversed the rows. Just printing backwards won't reverse it.

Comment: First see here to [reverse each inner array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java) then finally do your bit flip.

Answer (score 0):

You're just printing the array not modifying it, You can modify the array using code below

```
public int[][] flipAndInvertImage(int[][] image) {
    int[][] newImage = new int[image.length][image.length];
    int l = 0, m;
    for (int[] ints : image) {
        m = 0;
        for (int j = image[0].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            newImage[l][m++] = ints[j] ^ 1;
        }
        l++;
    }
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: thanks ! little bit of understanding i want to know why we are using l & m variable i didn't get that

Comment: @MustafaAhmed for row number and column number of the new array