# Reverse an array of integers using recursion without creating a second array and without an index

Tags: java

I am banging my head against the wall with this one. Here is what I have so far:

```java
public int[] Problem5(int[] myArray) {
    end = myArray.length;
    int temp = 0;
    
    if(beginning > end) {
        return myArray;
    }
    else {
        temp = myArray[beginning];
        myArray[beginning] = myArray[end];
        myArray[end] = temp;
    }
    beginning ++;
    end--;
    
    return Problem5(myArray);
}
```

Firstly, I think I have to figure out how to not reset "end" to the array length each time. I'm not sure how to handle that because I need to set it the first time.

Secondly, I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at the line "myArray[beginning] = myArray[end];".  I'm not sure how to handle that in the if statement.

Comment: What does your professor / teacher mean by "without an index" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reverse an int array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java)

Comment: @Moob -- I can't speak for the O/P, but my guess is "No". The O/P has specific requirements to use recursion and "without an index". I'm not sure what is meant by the latter.

Comment: By the way, the requirement to use recursion does not necessarily mean the recursive method has to be `int[] Problem5(int[] myArray)`. You could code, for example, a different method that uses recursion, such as `public static int [] reverse (int [] arr)` or `public static int [] reverse (int [] arr, int foo)`. The method `Problem5 (int[] myArray)` would call that method.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer the only parameters into the method is the array of integers.  I cannot change those parameters, therefore I cannot use any index parameters.

Comment: Yes, I assume `public int[] Problem5(int[] myArray)` is mandatory. But, within that, you should be able to use indexes.  I would guess you would also be allowed to use a different method that *does* take values of indexes parameters. But, I suspect it would have to be a *method you code*.  That would prohibit using built-in methods of `Collections` or `Arrays` API.

Comment: @poet_will You would need to somehow keep track of the index. Are you allowed to use class variable (static) or instance variable for that? Or another method with array and index parameters, which will be the actual recursive method, and you will call it inside `Problem5`?

Comment: Off-topic: I noticed `public int[] Problem5` is an instance method, but references no instance variables. Should it be `static` instead of an instance method?

Comment: @Chaosfire yes I can use class and method variables.  The method cannot take in a parameter to be used as the index.

Comment: @poet_will: I don't think you understand what we are saying. Yes, you are not allowed to change the return type, the name, or the parameter types or order of the `Problem5` method. But, we are suggesting you code an additional method that uses recursion, and  takes what parameters you need to solve the problem. Let's say you code a method `foo`. Somewhere inside `Problem5`, you call `foo`.  It will be `foo` that does the recursion. Chaosfire also wants to know if you are allowed to add instance variables to the class.

Comment: Or, there could be instance variables already in the class you are allowed to use.

Comment: There seems to be some sort of misunderstanding or miscommunication here. I suggest you talk with your professor / teacher. It might help if you show the professor / teacher this page.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means there is something wrong with how you are updating your variables.
you have to try reverse an array using recursion:

```
public class Main {
   static int beginning = 0;
   static int end;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
       end = myArray.length - 1;
       Problem5(myArray);
       for (int num : myArray) {
           System.out.print(num + " ");
       }
   }

   public static void Problem5(int[] myArray) {
       if (beginning >= end) {
           return;
       } else {
           int temp = myArray[beginning];
           myArray[beginning] = myArray[end];
           myArray[end] = temp;
       }
       beginning++;
       end--;
       Problem5(myArray);
   }
}
```

Before the elements and in the if statement i cheked `beginning >= end` in order to avoid the variable error.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Unfortunately I cannot set myArray.length outside of the method.  There are other methods in the class that use the same "myArray" name and I cannot change it.

Comment: @poet_will : The code in main in this answer is just for test / demonstration. The code you need, in the `Problem5` method doesn't set the length of the array.

Comment: @poet_will:  Within the `Problem5` method, `myArray` is a *local* variable name. If there happens to be an instance or class variable also named `myArray`, that variable name is hidden by the local.  Search for "Java variable shadowing". Within `Problem5` method, you won't know if local variable name `myArray` refers to the instance variable of the same name unless you test for that. If `Problem5` is part of `class Foo`, you couldh ave`public class Foo { int [] myArray; ... public void bar () { ... int [] bat = {100,50,-20,80,80,80,70,-40,10}; int [] bin = Problem5 (bat); ...}`

Comment: @poet_will this means that if there is another variable named `myArray` defined at a higher scope (i.e. in a class), it will be 'shadowed' in the method. The method will only see and manipulate the `myArray` that was passed to it. not the class-level unless we refert to it

Answer (score 1):

In the solution below you can reverse the array without any extra space, no extra array, and no temp for swapping the start and end of the array.

```
    public int[] Problem5(int[] arr) {
        return reverse(arr, 0, arr.length - 1); // use length - 1 to avoid index out of bound in accessing array
    }

    // By this method you can pass the new start and end 
    // Also you will do the recursion by this method
    private static int[] reverse(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
        if (start > end) {
            return arr;
        }

        // swap integers without temp
        // x, y = 2, 3
        // x = x + y = 2 + 3 = 5
        // y = x - y = 5 - 3 = 2
        // x = x - y = 5 - 2 = 3
        arr[start] = arr[start] + arr[end];
        arr[end] = arr[start] - arr[end];
        arr[start] = arr[start] - arr[end];

        //Move the indexes
        start++;
        end--;

        return reverse(arr, start, end);
    }
```

Solution with simple swapping:

```
    public int[] Problem5(int[] arr) {
        return reverse(arr, 0, arr.length - 1); // use length - 1 to avoid index out of bound in accessing array
    }

    // By this method you can pass the new start and end 
    // Also you will do the recursion by this method
    private static int[] reverse(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
        if (start > end) {
            return arr;
        }

        int temp = arr[start];
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = temp;

        //Move the indexes
        start++;
        end--;

        return reverse(arr, start, end);
    }
```

Comment: These methods take in a start and end index values.  The method parameter I have only takes in an Array.  Therefore I'm trying to solve the problem by using only the array and variables that I create.

Comment: @poet_will here also the Method Problem5 just takes one input (the array). then we create another method that can accept more input and to the recursion. By the way, if you need to use recursion you need somehow pass the start and end variables to the next method call. There is no magic, except using`ThreadLocal` which I don't recommend for solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Place your start and end as parameters to your method.

```
public int[] Problem5(int[] myArray, int start, int end) {

    int temp = 0;

    if(start > end) {
        return myArray;
    }
    else {
        temp = myArray[beginning];
        myArray[beginning] = myArray[end];
        myArray[end] = temp;
    }
    start++;
    end--;

    return Problem5(myArray, start end);
}
```

Comment: I cannot change the method parameters.

Comment: This will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

That was a challenge, and I had to look it up.

Utilize the *[Arrays#copyOfRange](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T%5B%5D,int,int))* method to *shallow copy* the array.

```java
<T> void reverse(T[] a) {
    if (a.length == 1) 
        return;
    T t = a[0];
    a[0] = a[a.length - 1];
    a[a.length - 1] = t;
    reverse(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length));
}
```

Alternately, here is an example using a starting and ending index.

```java
<T> void reverse(T[] a, int i, int j) {
    if (i == j) 
        return;
    T t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = t;
    reverse(a, ++i, --j);
}
```

Comment: `reverse(copyOfRange(...))` won't work because it will reverse a _copy_ of the array, but you want to reverse a subrange of the original array.

Comment: The O/P is a student, and unlikely to have encountered generics at this point.  So, why not stick with `int`?

Answer (score 1):

With an instance variable, a solution can be like this:

```
public class Test {

    private int currentIndex = 0; // It probably needs a better name

    public int[] Problem5(int[] myArray) {
        if (currentIndex == myArray.length / 2) {
            // You have reached the middle of the array.
            // Everything is swapped
            currentIndex = 0; // Reset index if you need to use the same instance again
            return myArray;
        }
        int firstIndex = currentIndex;
        int secondIndex = myArray.length - 1 - firstIndex;

        int temp = myArray[firstIndex];
        myArray[firstIndex] = myArray[secondIndex];
        myArray[secondIndex] = temp;
        currentIndex++; // Update the index before the next recursive call
        return Problem5(myArray);
    }
}
```

Also, you can use the second method to do the actual recursion, without changing `Problem5`:

```
public class Test {

    public int[] Problem5(int[] myArray) {
        // This method has remained unchanged
        return actualRecursiveMethod(myArray, 0);
    }

    private static int[] actualRecursiveMethod(int[] myArray, int index) {
        // The 'magic' happens here
        if (index == myArray.length / 2) {
            // You have reached the middle of the array.
            // Everything is swapped.
            return myArray;
        }
        int secondIndex = myArray.length - 1 - index;

        int temp = myArray[index];
        myArray[index] = myArray[secondIndex];
        myArray[secondIndex] = temp;
        // Call recursively with next index
        return actualRecursiveMethod(myArray, index + 1);
    }
}
```